# Moment - Get the start of day of the local time and add a different timezone

Tags: momentjs

Imagine that we have a timestamp, for example **1571140569** (*Tuesday, 15 October 2019 11:56:09*). I need to get the start, in this case *Tuesday, 15 October 2019 00:00:00*. Then i need to apply timezone, imagine "America/Lima" (GTM -7h), we want to show *Tuesday, 14 October 2019 07:00:00*

I use this code

```
  moment_timezone(1571140569).startOf("day").tz("America/Lima");
```

But doesn´t work. Return *Tuesday, 15 October 2019 00:00:00*.

So: Somebody know how can i get the start of timestamp  and then apply timezone?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you to get the output you are expecting.

```js
const date = moment(moment.unix(1571140569).utc().startOf('day')).tz("America/Lima").format('LLLL');
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```